# Event Listener for Delete Button not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a button to delete table data, for some reason when I click the button my click event listener does nothing. If you wish to see all the code here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/kiva-gordon/pen/ExmWebm)

```
const showExpenses = () => {

  const table = document.getElementById('expenseTable');

    table.innerHTML = '';
  
  for(let i = 0; i < expenses.length; i++){
        expenseTable.innerHTML += `
            <tr >
                <td class="expItem">${expenses[i].name}</td>
                <td class="expItem">${expenses[i].date}</td>
                <td class="expItem">$${expenses[i].amount}</td>
                <td><a class="deleteButton" onclick="handleRemove(${expenses[i].id})">
                    Delete</td>
            </tr>
        `;
    }
}

//Remove buttom
const handleRemove = e => {
  const item = e.target.closest('.expItem');
  
  // Remove the listener, to avoid memory leaks.
  item.querySelector('.deleteButton')
    .removeEventListener('onclick', handleRemove);
  
  item.parentElement.removeChild(item);
};
```

Comment: You take `e` in `handleRemove` and treat it as an event but then attach `onclick="handleRemove(${expenses[i].id})"` as a listener so you'd pass the `id` on click.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the way to do this would be set an event listener on all delete buttons and give them data-id attributes so you can retrieve the id when clicked. Then access the closest `<tr>` and finally use jQuery `remove()`

```
    expenseTable.innerHTML += `...
            <td><a class="deleteButton" href="#" data-id="${expenses[i].id}">Delete</a></td>
        ...
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').on('click', '.deleteButton', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent the href default 
     // if you need to access the id...
     let deleteID = $(this).data('id');
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   })
})
```

Comment: @KivaGordon - I updated my answer to use jQuery and event delegation

Comment: I've never used jQuery before but I got it to work now, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @KivaGordon - ha! I saw this `${expenses[i].id}` in your code and for some reason thought jQuery, when it was just a template literal. Apologies, misread